# How to know if a variable is only a "pointer" to another object or if it can exist independently

Tags: .net, powershell, oop

```
$App = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application; 

$PackageFullPath = 'C:\SSISPackage.dtsx'; 

$Package = $App.LoadPackage($PackageFullPath, $null, 0);

$x = $Package.Connections
$x.Remove("Something")

$App.SaveToXml($PackageFullPath, $Package, $null)
```

My question is when I assign the instance to a new variable `$x`, how do I know when I call a method on `$x` that it will reflect on `$Package`? So when I remove someting from `$x`, will it also remove that thing from `$Package`? If the answer is "it depends" how can I know without setting up an experiment?

Comment: I'm just making an educated guess here but since you're NOT copying the whole object, e.g. $x=$package how is $x supposed to link to $package? Thus, I'd say that $x.remove("something") will not affect $package. If you google PowerShell Pointers there are some useful articles on the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Because the `$Package.Connections` property contains an instance of a .NET *reference type*, namely [`Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Connections`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.runtime.connections), `$x` and `$Package.Connections` reference the very same collection instance, so `$x.Remove("Something")` is the same as `$Package.Connections.Remove("Something")`

---

The behavior depends on whether a given value is an instance of a .NET [*reference type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) or [*value type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-types):

- When *reference-type* instances are assigned to a (new) variable / passed as an argument, it is the *reference* ("pointer") to the actual data that is copied, which means that both the original value and the target variable / parameter refer to the *same object*.
- By contrast, assigning / passing a *value-type* instance makes a copy of the *value itself*, resulting in *independent copies* of the data.

You can examine an object stored in a given variable `$x` as follows: `$true` indicates a value-type instance, `$false` a reference-type instance:

```
$x.GetType().IsValueType
```

Note that *collection-like* types, including *arrays*, are *reference-type* instances, so `$x` and `$Package.Connections` in the code in your question will refer to the same collection.
By contrast, all so-called *primitive* types, such as numbers, are *value types*.

If you don't want to rely on inspection *at runtime*, you can examine *the documentation* for a given type, which (with the language set to C#) will use the following "type-kind" identifiers:

- Reference types:

  - `class` (e.g. [`ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList))
- Value types:

  - `struct` (e.g., [`DateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime))
  - `enum` (e.g., [`PlatformID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.PlatformID))